# Can't remember if one said Elokai Netzor or not?

Tags: tefilla, shemoneh-esrei

If someone says the individual's Shemona Esrei and they can't remember whether they said the conclusion (which the chazzan's repetition does not say beginning Elokai Netzor) are they still yotzei saying the individual's shemona esrei?

Comment: I don't have an explicit source but I'd venture to say he is still "yotzei". EN is not one of the berachot, it's a personal supplication which was appended to the SE but not as binding. At most, we find ([Yoma 53b](https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.53b.3?with=all&lang=bi)) that one who doesn't take leave of the King (by saying "oseh shalom") is disrespectful but his fulfillment of the SE is not voided.

Comment: Thats what I thought. I just wanted to make sure. "May the expressions of my mouth and the thoughts of my heart find favor..." Since that is said twice one tends to forget if they space out if they said Elokei Netzor or not.

Comment: Also I am guessing since the person is "yotzei" a person shouldn't repeat Shemona Esrei again even if they wanted to as that would be a prayer in vain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. That is just a customary addition (see Berakhot 17a that records this as the practice of an individual rabbi). It is found in the Siddur of [Rav Amram Gaon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amram_Gaon) (ed. Harpenes Seder Tefilla). This work underwent some evolution, but its core is from the ninth century. It is also found in the Siddur of [Rav Sa'adya Gaon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saadia_Gaon) from the early 10th century, (ed. Assaf pg. 19). [Rashi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashi) (11th cent.) (Berakhot 29b s.v. Tahanunim) similarly indicates that it is a customary part of the liturgy. Similarly, see [Mahzor Vitry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simhah_ben_Samuel_of_Vitry#The_Vitry_Machzor) (89).

It is not listed as one of the 18 blessings established in Megillah 17a, or the additional blessing added by Sh'muel HaKattan recorded in Berakhot 28b, which form the required prayer text (see Rambam's Hilkhot Tefilla 2:2).

Comment: The siddur underwent some evolution? No no no! The Rambam davened from an ArtScroll siddur, of course. ;P +1